# Why is this cover incorrect?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, covering-spaces

I have been trying to construct a 3-fold cover of the punctured torus. Specifically, I am trying to construct a once-punctured genus 2 surface.
Here is an attempt. I know it's incorrect because I have a 2-fold cover that is a genus 2 surface with one boundary component, but by Euler characteristic calculations, the cover should be 3-sheeted. What is wrong with this construction, and are there any ideas for how to produce the correct cover?

[image]

Comment: To me it looks like you have double-coverered each of the face and $7$ edges, but you have only $9$ vertices upstairs to cover $5$ vertices downstairs. Somehow for this to work you need to have $3$ distinct vertices upstairs to cover the "outer" vertex downstairs. That said, this looks like a perfectly fine $2$-sheeted ramified cover

Comment: I don't know if it helps you to think of fundamental groups, but the subgroup $$\pi_1(\Sigma_2 \setminus \{\mathrm{pt}\}) \cong \langle a^2, ab, ba, b^2 \rangle \subset \langle a \rangle * \langle b \rangle = \pi_1(\Sigma_1 \setminus \{\mathrm{pt}\})$$ is of index $3$, so something along those lines should work